# Joomla template php checking if viewing login registration pages

Tags: php, joomla

So in my *templates/templatename/index.php* I did the following code to check if the user is viewing the registration, login, reminder or forgot password pages as to **NOT** display / insert adverts on those particular pages.

But for some reason my code is not working and I can't figure out why.

```
<?php if(JFactory::getUser()->guest) : ?>
<?php if(JRequest::getVar('view') !== 'login' || JRequest::getVar('view') !== 'reset' || JRequest::getVar('view') !== 'remind' || JRequest::getVar('view') !== 'registration') : ?>
<?php include(JPATH_BASE . '/' . 'advert.php'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Pages / urls the advert.php includes should not be present on.

> index.php?option=com_users&view=login
>
> index.php?option=com_users&view=reset
>
> index.php?option=com_users&view=remind
>
> index.php?option=com_users&view=registration

Thanks to anyone who can point out what I am doing wrong.

//EDIT :
SEF Url's too

> /login.html
>
> /reset.html
>
> /remind.html
>
> /registration.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of || [OR] use && [AND]

```
if(JRequest::getVar('view') !== 'login' && JRequest::getVar('view') !== 'reset' && JRequest::getVar('view') !== 'remind' && JRequest::getVar('view') !== 'registration')
```

here is some explanation from [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

> $a or $b   TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE. 
>   $a and $b  TRUE if both $a and $b are TRUE.

Other way you can try is using $option instead of $view

```
$option != 'com_user'
```

in joomla 3.x you can take this parameter by

```
$option   = $app->input->getCmd('option', '');
```

take a look at protostar default template

Comment: Thanks switching from OR to AND is where my mistake was :)